# Permission "deny from all" set from apache or htaccess doesn't give forbidden on require php

Tags: apache, .htaccess, wamp

I'm on local development wamp and I've setup a restricted access to some files inside a folder (I've tried first setting the rules inside apache vhost file and the in the .htaccess created in the folder) but if I try access those files from the browser it works and give me "Forbidden" but if I call one php file in the folder using require function it doesn't give me any error..
I've also made a check in the php file using is_writable but it doesn't return false..

Where's the problem? Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: Your require via PHP uses a local file system path, and not a URL, I presume? Then HTTP is not even involved, so any restrictions you configured regarding access via HTTP, do not apply in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found one reason: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27609
So one problem is the php check that returns false just if thr read-only attribute is enabled. Now I'm trying to understand why it require the file that should be locked by the .htacess